# Ошибка при использовании giQiwiApi

Tags: python, telegram-bot, qiwi, платежи

Использую библиотеку `telebot` для разработки бота. В данный момент настраиваю оплату через `glQiwiApi`. Все данные и токены находятся `БД Sqlite3`. При использовании кода, возникает **ошибка**:

```
glQiwiApi.utils.errors.NetworkError: Invalid response with content type application/octet-stream: ""
```

Можете, пожалуйста, еще подсказать, какую библиотеку лучше использовать для настройки оплаты через `QIWI` кошелек.

**Код:**

```
    async def payment():

            connect = sqlite3.connect("packegers.db", check_same_thread=False)
            cursor = connect.cursor()

            cursor.execute("SELECT numer FROM bankDet")
            qiwi_number = cursor.fetchone()[0]
            cursor.execute("SELECT qiwiToken FROM bankDet")
            qiwi_token = cursor.fetchone()[0]
            cursor.execute(f"SELECT packValue FROM packs WHERE packName='{m}'")
            value = int(cursor.fetchone()[0])
            cursor.execute("SELECT numer publicP2Ptoken FROM bankDet")
            publicP2Ptoken = cursor.fetchone()[0]
            cursor.execute("SELECT numer secretP2Ptoken FROM bankDet")
            secretP2Ptoken = cursor.fetchone()[0]

            async with QiwiWrapper(secret_p2p=secretP2Ptoken) as w:
                bill = await w.create_p2p_bill(amount=value, comment=f'Покупка пакета {m}')

                if (await w.check_p2p_bill_status(bill_id=bill.bill_id)) == 'PAID':

                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Платеж прошел успешно! Вот ваш пакет))")

                    docID = cursor.execute(f"SELECT packID FROM packs WHERE packName='{m}'").fetchone()[0]
                    print(docID)
                    msg = bot.send_document(message.chat.id, docID)
                    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, buyPack)

                else:

                    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Пакет не оплачен((")

                    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, buyPack)

                    print(await bill.paid)

    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
    asyncio.run(payment())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При настройке оплаты выяснилось, что использовать соответствующие библиотеки небезопасно. Поэтому я решил использовать парсинг при помощи либы requests. Вот ссылка на статью: https://itnan.ru/post.php?c=1&p=470023